# Look for special characters in url mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http : //www . mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L] 

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/current-activity/  $1/guide-tourisme/? 

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/current-activities/([^/]+/[^.]+\.html)$    /$1/guide-tourisme-activities/$2 [NC,R=301,L,NE]
```

Hello could you help me please, I need to redirect the url but this part of the pattern doesnt work correctly for this part:

```
 (.^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

I need to find in the url special charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong due to `^`, try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/old-url/([^/]+/[^.]+\.html)$ /$1/new-url/$2 [NC,R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: When the path has comma doesnt work correctly:                                                                  /$1/new-url/$2{HERE: (comma, numbers, comma, numbers),123,456}.html?&args=manythingsas7as4as7a

Comment: http://www.localhost.com/country/current-activities/diving/deshaies-lowland,207,585.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD00MDQmYWN0aW9uPWZpY2hlJmlkPTMxNjYmfA%3D%3D I need to redirect dynamically to http://www.localhost.com/country/MY-NEW-ACTIVITY/diving/deshaies-lowland,207,585.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD00MDQmYWN0aW9uPWZpY2hlJmlkPTMxNjYmfA%3D%3D

Comment: http: //www. localhost.com/barbados/current-activities/diving/deshaies-lowland,207,585.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD00MDQmYWN0aW9uPWZpY2hlJmlkPTMxNjYmfA%3D%3D  It did not work. :S I put my full htaccess.

Comment: If I erase this{,207,585}  part of the url it work but with numbers and comma doesnt... :/

Comment: It doesnt this rule just redirect without numbers and comma. I understand bad.

Comment: Im using incognito window. Could you please check your solution that its very good but with this problem it is not the optimal solution. In this part dont check for numbers and comma: "[^.]+"

Comment: I really appreciate your help Im around the solution thanks to you. Do you have another way of doing this logic?

Comment: I prove again your solution and you are right It work with comma and numbers but when the url end with a number It doesn't, look:                             {number}{comma}​‌​.html --> It work,                                                    {comma}{number}​‌​.html --> It doesn't work. Why?